# DateTime Class. shorter way to set date to start of the day (or without time altogether)

Tags: php, datetime

Currently when I want to get today's date irrespective of time, I have to do the following.

```
$Date = new DateTime('now');
$Date->setTime(0,0,0);
```

Is there a more eloquent way of doing this? Preferably a one-liner

Comment: Just use `today` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP 5.4+

```
$Date = (new DateTime('now'))->setTime(0,0,0);
```

Or

```
$Date = new DateTime('midnight');
```

Comment: @MarkBaker I thought class member access on instantiation was new in 5.4?

Comment: Perfect! thank you. will accept answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: True, my bad... I was thinking of setTime() returning a DateTime rather than a null

Comment: @JohnConde Take it easy John. buona notte, ciao.